# How to bypass bot detection on google using python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, bots

So my code was working fine until a couple of days when I keep getting this error message from google: Couldn't sign you in. **This browser or app may not be secure.**

Here is my code:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions

chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--lang=en-US")
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {'intl.accept_languages': 'en,en_US'})
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging', 'enable-automation'])
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
chrome_options.set_capability('dom.webdriver.enabled', False)
chrome_options.add_argument(f'--user-data-dir={PATHS.CHROME_SYS_PATH}')
chrome_options.add_argument(f'--profile-directory={sub_dir}')
chrome_dirver = Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=PATHS.CHROME_DRIVER)
chrome_driver.get(r"https://www.google.com/")
```

Google keeps throwing the same error over and over!